# Optmize svg data stored in javascript objects

Tags: javascript, svg, compression, frontend, minify

I have a bunch of `svg` path data stored in javascript objects from a project that I'm trying to adapt to my needs, the format is something like this:

```
var clothData={
"cloth0":{
    "frontSide":{
        "cX":0,
        "cY":0,
        "path": [{
            "type": "path",
            "style": [{
                "attr": "d",
                "val": "/* d element info */" 
            }]
        }, /* ... */ ]
    }
},
"cloth1":{
    "frontSide":{
        "cX":0,
        "cY":0,
        "path": [{
            "type": "path",
            "style": [{
                "attr": "d",
                "val": "/* d element info */" 
            }]
         }, /* ... */
        ]
    }
 }, /* ... */ 
}
```

The data is then loaded dynamically into a `g` elemento inside an `svg` depending on user action. I'm currently using [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) `.data` function to load the `"path"` property in the element.

I use the objects as reference data, in my code there's something like this: `svgElement.select(partSelector).data(data.frontSide.path)`, where `partSelector` is the selector to get to the portion of the svg to change and `data` is obtained from the object.

I don't know what tool where used to generate the script containing those objects, the issue is that the file is to big to be served, `10MB` after minified.

Is there a way that I can compress the data even more in order to reduce its size?

I don't need to use *d3.js* or the script with the objects, I just need a way that I can modify the content of the svg dynamically according with the data without using an `10MB` file.

Comment: `modify the content of the svg dynamically according with the data` what does that mean? This ain't clear to me. In your snippet it seems that the only things changing on the objects are the `val` keys. Is that right, or does it only seem like that in the short snippet? Then, how about turning gzip-compression on on your server? This format should be highly compressible, I'd guess to maybe 2-3MB. Depends on the rest of the file.

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear, I use the objects as reference data, in my code there's something like this: `svgElement.select(partSelector).data(data.frontSide.path)`, where `partSelector` is the selector to get to the portion of the svg to change and `data` is obtained from the object.